# Does a singleton with only one public method make sense?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class that exposes only one public method and it's a singleton.

Would it make sense to just get rid of the class thing and declare properties and methods as global variables and functions? And then exporting only the one "public" function.

Is there anything wrong about using global variables?

Comment: Does the class have state?

Comment: You mention "exporting". Are you using ES6 modules? Then there's no global variables anyway.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by state? I have properties on `this` that are used and setted by different methods. I am using ES6 modules, but I bundle in different formats, is this relevant?

Comment: Yes, I mean data properties that are updated by methods, so the public method does different things depending on the property values.

Comment: Yes the class has states. Could global variables be a valid substitute or should I stick with the singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, avoid the singleton pattern altogether if your class has state, since that becomes [global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/66652). But if you can't (easily):

> Can I get rid of the `class` thing and declare properties and methods as variables and functions? And then exporting only the one "public" function?

Yes, this makes total sense with modules. A module is essentially a singleton already (it gets evaluated only once). Notice the variables and functions wouldn't be global, they're scoped to the module.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it says what I wanted to know, that is if I could get rid of the class and use "global" variables instead (which is fine because they are scoped to the module, and I trust they don't suffer any limitation). However I don't understand why a state in a class would become a global state, and also how would this be a problem if the global state is being read and set only by one class instance (the singleton).

Comment: State in a *singleton* becomes global state, because you have only one global instance.

Comment: But that's just semantics, a singleton state doesn't behave differently from a non singleton state, isn't it? And just to double check, the fact that a module "gets evaluated only once" doesn't have any limitation, like if one of the states (now global variables) were set depending on DOM events, that logic would still work right?

Comment: No, instance state is not behaving any differently whether it's a singleton or not, it's just that global state is bad for various reasons. And yes, the logic of your singleton will work the same in a module, "*it gets only evaluated once*" is not a limitation but rather the reason it works the same as a singleton that "*gets only instantiated once*".

Comment: All right. Thank you very much for the answer and all the subsequent clarifications!